# Struggling with Ajax Post Image

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I've been really struggling posting image data to a Java server. I get 400 (Bad request every time).

Some things I've tried

```
var imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;

ctx.drawImage(renderer.domElement,- (renderer.domElement.width/2 - canvas.width/2),- (renderer.domElement.height/2 - canvas.height/2), renderer.domElement.width, renderer.domElement.height);
var resizedImageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
$("#sceneThumbImage").attr("src",resizedImageData);


var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = '/scene/'+currentScene.id+'/thumb';

ajax.open("POST",url,false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(resizedImageData);
```

And

```
$.post('/scene/'+currentScene.id+'/thumb',resizedImageData,function(){console.log('success')},function(e){console.log('failed',e)});
```

The Java method

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/scene/{sceneId}/thumb", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveSceneThumb(
            @PathVariable("sceneId") String sceneId,
            @RequestParam("thumbName") String thumbName,
            DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest request) {

        // If not logged in, return early
        if (!isLoggedIn(request))
            return getErrorResponse(1234, "not logged in");

        try {
            // Create and populate the thumb with the new bitmap
            //File file = new File(Constants.TEMP_DIR_PATH + thumbName);
            //request.getFile("thumb").transferTo(file);

            java.io.File file = new java.io.File(Constants.TEMP_DIR_PATH
                    + thumbName);
            request.getFile("thumb").transferTo(file);

            // upload thumb to the scenes bucket
            s3UploadService.uploadFile(assetsBucket, file);

            return getSuccessResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return getErrorResponse(1234, "Error uploading scene thumb");
        }
    }   }   }
```

Each and every time it's a bad request. If anyone knows of an easy way to debug this or can spot something I'm doing wrong, please let me know!

Comment: are you trying to upload to server side or just add the image to a canvas?

Comment: Upload to a Java server.  I'll add server function.

Comment: Not sure of `'Content-Type', 'application/upload'`.. I would have used `multipart/form-data` ? 400 seems the request is not correct/formed properly.

Comment: Yep that helped. I'm getting Java errors now which helps.

Comment: an i guess that's because thumbName is not found

Comment: Getting "500 (Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found)" Is this the same issue?

Comment: are you able to share the html ? is this enclosed in a form?